# invoking shell command on groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to run below groovy script and produce the result of it as expected with grep command. instead of printing the result. it populate entire curl output without greping the DOCTYPE

```
def print(){
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()

def proc ='''curl --silent --request POST --header "content-type:application/json"       www.google.co.in | grep DOCTYPE'''.execute()

proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(2000)
println sout
}

print()
```

Expected result as we get it on linux terminal

```
 curl --silent --request POST --header "content-type:application/json" www.google.co.in | grep DOCTYPE
```

Can someone help me with this situation, how to resolve it.

result should be the final one after the series of condition passed on commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just throw piped bash commands into a String and hope for the best, it just wont work (mostly as piping, etc is performed by the shell, which you won't be using)

You can do things like this:

```
// A curl process
def curl = ['curl', '--silent', '--request', 'POST', '--header', 'content-type:application/json', 'www.google.co.in'].execute()

// A grep process
def grep = ['grep', 'DOCTYPE'].execute()

// Pipe the output of curl into grep and get the text
(curl | grep).text
```

To do this in pure Groovy would be:

```
def response = new URL('https://www.google.co.in').with {
    openConnection().with {
        setRequestProperty('Content-type', 'application/json')
        requestMethod = 'POST'
        doOutput = true
        if (responseCode > 400) {
            errorStream.text
        } else {
            inputStream.text
        }
    }
}

println response.readLines().findAll { it.contains('DOCTYPE') }
```

But as you're in Jenkins, I'm not sure this would work